# Syntax error in Break statement in Python - help needed

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner in Python so I have been experiencing some issues in loops if python. My concerns involves 'while' loop and 'break' statement.

I have followed as it is mentioned in book and also cross verified from internet but my code does not work still gives me same error.

```
for i in range(5): j=j+2
    print('i:',i, ',j:',j) if j==6:break
```

Gives me error as below

```
File "<ipython-input-5-5ff0ac309f49>", line 5
    print('i:',i, ',j:',j) if j==6:break
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Could you fix the format of your code and correct the indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use correct indents in python. Since there are no concept of braces, if you want a block to be in a scope, the indents matter. You can refer to this [example](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php)

Your code in correction will look like:

```
j = 0
for i in range(5):
    j = j + 2
    print('i:', i, ',j:', j)
    if j == 6:
        break
```

basically, think like every bracket is like a new line+ 4 space indents.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks Kris. So we need to have +4 space indents when loops are involved?

Comment: Its not about loops alone, in python every block is identified by proper indent spaces. Please read more on this in official documentations. It simply makes multiple statements in single line invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In python leading spaces in a meaningful. This code works well.

```py
j=0
for i in range(5):
    j=j+2
    print('i:',i, ',j:',j)
    if j==6:
        break
```